# Can AudioGraph play streams?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, uwp

Due to application constraints, I can't use an `IStorageFile` in my UWP application, so, `audioGraph.CreateFileInputNodeAsync()` is not an option.
I can only get the (I/O) `Stream` with the sound file's contents.

Is there a way to configure an `AudioGraph` to use such stream as input?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to configure an AudioGraph to use such stream as input?

According to the [Audio graphs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/audio-graphs) class, there're three kinds of input node: "Device input node", "File input node" and "Audio frame input node". Unfortunately no stream input node as you want. You need to convert the stream to [`StroageFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile) and then use `CreateFileInputNodeAsync()` method.

> Can AudioGraph play streams?

If you just want to play the streams without using `StorageFile` class, you may consider using [`MediaPlayer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer). Creating the [`MediaSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Core.MediaSource)  from `IRandomAccessStream` by  `CreateFromStream` method. For example:

XAML Code:

```
<MediaPlayerElement x:Name="mediaplayer" AutoPlay="True"></MediaPlayerElement>
<Button x:Name="btnmedia" Click="btnmedia_Click" Content="media play"></Button>
```

Code behind:

```
private async void btnmedia_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    Stream filestream = buffers.AsStream();
    IRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = filestream.AsRandomAccessStream();
    MediaSource mediasource = MediaSource.CreateFromStream(randomAccessStream, "mp3");
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.Source = mediasource;
    mediaplayer.SetMediaPlayer(player);
}
```

Additionally, it is strange that you cannot use `StorageFile` class in a UWP app. It is an important class for file system. I think you should consider to resolve this constraints if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an AudioFrameOutputNode and feed it the entire binary contents of the stream, assuming you can read the whole stream into a binary buffer in memory.

If you have to coordinate concurrent reading from the stream and feeding the data to the AudioFrameOutputNode, things get more involved, but it is still doable.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like an option. Sadly, not out of the box.